# What is wrong with [If you want to get good score] VS [If you want to get "a" good score]

Tags: grammar

which one is correct?

> If you want to get good score  (on google about 76 results)
>
> If you want to get a good score (on google about 328 results)

I have checked both sentences on google and checked how many lists on both, the research results show that both are okay, are they right for the grammar.

PS: "If you want to get good scores" <--this sentence is from learning English website

Comment: There are many possible scores, low scores, high scores, and scores in the middle. You want one of them in the "good" range.  You want to get **a good score**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving "good score" the [zero article](https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-article-grammar-1692619).  This transforms the noun phrase from its intended meaning into either a proper noun (the name of something) or a mass noun (which is nonsense).

With the zero article, your sentence is basically saying that there is a person or physical object (like a book or something) with the name "good score", and that you want to "get" this thing.  This is clearly not your intended message, and so it is grammatically wrong.

Plural nouns get the zero article by default, just as mass nouns do, which is why "If you want to get good score**s**" is correct.

An example of the proper use of the zero article would be in something like the word "Rose".  With the indefinite or definite article (a, the) it means a flower.  With the zero article instead, it is a common girl's name.  As the [article I linked above](https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-article-grammar-1692619) gives in example:

> My mother's name is Rose. I gave her a rose on Mother's Day.

If I changed this to say:

> I gave her Rose on Mother's Day.

It now means that I have given my mother a girl named Rose, which depending on context, could either mean something like "giving her a granddaughter named Rose" or "giving her a [chattel slave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattel_slavery#Chattel_slavery) named Rose".

Comment: Hi could you have me some sentences examples for both, thanks

Comment: Does this added example help? Note that while in writing, the proper name "Rose" has a capital letter R, when spoken, you can't hear capitalization.  So articles really are required for the language to work.